# Return in define (switch)

Tags: c

I'm writing a code with a switch function. I want my default code to print "Error" and make the program stop running. Should I add a `return 1;` at the end of my default?

If so, is this right?

```
switch (course3)
{
    case 'I':
        course3 = 5;
        grade3 = grade3 + 2;
        break;
    case 'O': 
        course3 = 4;
        grade3 = grade3 - 3;
        break;
    case 'A': 
        course3 = 3;
        grade3 = grade3 + 8;
        break;
    case 'D': 
        course3 = 2;
        grade3 = grade3*1.06;
        break;
    case 'L': 
        course3 = 1;
        grade3 = 10 * sqrt(grade3);
        break;
    default:
        printf("Error\n");
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: Quick answer: yes. you should also have a `break` line like in your other cases

Comment: @RNar There's no need for `break` after `return`, since nothing after `return` is executed.

Comment: You should be able to answer your own question by compiling and testing the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming this block of code resides in the `main` function, then yes using `return 1;` will accomplish this, since returning from `main` is equivalent to calling `exit`.

If this block is not in `main`, then the `return` statement will simply return to the calling function.  In that case you need to explicitly call `exit(1);` to get the same result.